# R drawing a barcode by giving the explicite position where to draw the black lines

Tags: r, plot, barcode, barcode-printing

Is there any function to draw a bar-code with R, which takes the height (or say the width = the number of lines) and the position where to draw a black lines.

Thanks for your help.

David.

Comment: Have you seen the package `barcode`?

Comment: It looks like `barcode` is intended for making "barcode plots" to represent distributions, rather than for creating product barcodes.

Answer (score 1):

You can print bar codes with the `zintr` package. For this to work, you'll need to install `zint` and then `zintr`. See the installation instructions on the [`zintr` development site](https://github.com/CannaData/zintr).

Then, to create a bar code:

```
library(zintr)

barcode_print("3.14159265", "pi.png")
```

[image]

If instead you want to draw a bar code, given a series of widths for each segment, here's some fake data for a demonstration using ggplot2. Real bar codes can have multiple segments for a given character, and the example below doesn't capture this. It just gives you an idea of how to draw the segments if you know their locations and widths.

```
library(ggplot2)

barcode = function(x, w, num) {

  bc = data.frame(x, w, num)
  bc$xpos = seq(min(bc$x)+0.15, max(bc$x)-0.15, length=nrow(bc))

  ggplot(bc) +
    geom_rect(aes(xmin=x - 0.5*w, xmax=x+0.5*w, ymin=0, ymax=1), 
              show.legend=FALSE, fill="black") +
    geom_text(aes(label=num, x=xpos, y=-0.07)) +
    coord_fixed(0.5) +
    theme_void()
}
```

Then, to run the function:

```
barcode(x=cumsum(0 + runif(12, 0.05, 0.1)),
        w=runif(12,0.01,0.05),
        num=sample(0:9, 12, replace=TRUE))
```

[image]