# ggplot2: Visualizing a long string (with only 2 words repeated in different ways) as a barplot

Tags: r, string, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a whatsapp conversation consisting of two categories of words:

```
bla bla bla bla
 <indig>fu fu</indig>
 <indig>fu fu</indig>
 bla bla bla bla bla bla.. bla bla bla bla bla
 <indig>fu</indig>?
 <indig>fu fu</indig>?
 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
 bla
 <indig>fu fu</indig>
 bla bla <indig>fu</indig>
 bla <indig>fu</indig>
 bla.. bla
 bla bla bla bla bla bla ??
 bla bla bla
 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
 bla bla <indig>fu</indig> bla
```

I want to visualise the `bla` and `fu` as a bar plot using 2 colors so that I can see where does `fu` color occurs (start, middle, end...) and where is `bla` color in majority. I only have an example and no code to show as of now:
[image]
Here the black color could be associated with `fu` and the white could be associated with `bla`. Any ideas how to plot something similar in `ggplot2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a function that takes a dichotomic vector `x` and plots a bar code in `ggplot2` graphics. The function is inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48845687/8245406) by SO user [eipi10](https://stackoverflow.com/users/496488/eipi10).

```r
x<-"bla bla bla bla
 <indig>fu fu</indig>
 <indig>fu fu</indig>
 bla bla bla bla bla bla.. bla bla bla bla bla
 <indig>fu</indig>?
 <indig>fu fu</indig>?
 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
 bla
 <indig>fu fu</indig>
 bla bla <indig>fu</indig>
 bla <indig>fu</indig>
 bla.. bla
 bla bla bla bla bla bla ??
 bla bla bla
 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
 bla bla <indig>fu</indig> bla"
x<-scan(textConnection(x), what = character())
y <- gsub("<indig>|</indig>|\\?", "", x)
y <- gsub("[^[:alpha:]]*", "", y)
y <- y[y != ""]
y
#>  [1] "bla" "bla" "bla" "bla" "fu"  "fu"  "fu"  "fu"  "bla" "bla" "bla" "bla"
#> [13] "bla" "bla" "bla" "bla" "bla" "bla" "bla" "fu"  "fu"  "fu"  "bla" "bla"
#> [25] "bla" "bla" "bla" "bla" "bla" "bla" "bla" "bla" "bla" "bla" "bla" "fu" 
#> [37] "fu"  "bla" "bla" "fu"  "bla" "fu"  "bla" "bla" "bla" "bla" "bla" "bla"
#> [49] "bla" "bla" "bla" "bla" "bla" "bla" "bla" "bla" "bla" "bla" "bla" "bla"
#> [61] "bla" "bla" "bla" "bla" "bla" "bla" "bla" "bla" "bla" "bla" "bla" "fu" 
#> [73] "bla"


library(ggplot2)

barcode <- function(x, black) {
  
  black <- if(missing(black)) x[1] else black
  r <- rle(x == black)
  x <- cumsum(r$lengths)[r$values]
  w <- r$lengths[r$values]
  
  bc <- data.frame(x, w)

  ggplot(bc) +
    geom_rect(aes(xmin = x - w, xmax = x, ymin = 0, ymax = 1), 
              show.legend=FALSE, fill="black") +
    theme_void() +
    theme(aspect.ratio = 1/2)
}

barcode(y, black = "bla")
```

[image]

```r
barcode(y, black = "fu")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Another example with binary numeric data.

```r
set.seed(2022)
y2 <- rbinom(100, 1, 0.5)
barcode(y2, black = 1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This definitely looks nicer than mine. I am trying to get my head around whether it is as faithful to the input data.

Comment: v nice. I thought this could be shortened by using `ggh4x::stat_rle` - and yes it can, but it's still a bit cumbersome. [It has led me to propose a feature request](https://github.com/teunbrand/ggh4x/issues/78#issue-1397904965) Dunno if teunbrand will find it interesting enough to work on it though.

Answer (score 5):

I think this basically falls into two parts - formatting the data and drawing the plot.

#### Formatting the data

```r
# Make one string
input_string <- paste(input_string, collapse = " ")

# delete everything <inside> angle brackets
input_string <- gsub("<.*?>", "", input_string)

# Split on spaces
input_string <- strsplit(input_string, "\\s")  |>
    unlist()

# delete all non-alpha e.g. "fu?" becomes "fu"
input_string <- gsub("[^[:alpha:]]", "", input_string)

words_to_plot <- c("fu", "bla")

binary_vector_to_plot <- input_string[input_string %in% words_to_plot]

plot_df <- data.frame(
    x = seq_along(binary_vector_to_plot),
    y = binary_vector_to_plot
)

head(plot_df)
#   x   y
# 1 1 bla
# 2 2 bla
# 3 3 bla
# 4 4 bla
# 5 5  fu
# 6 6  fu
```

#### Drawing the plot

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(plot_df) +
    geom_vline(
        aes(
            xintercept = x,
            color = y
        )
    ) +
    theme_bw() +
    scale_color_manual(
        values = c("white", "black")
    ) +
    ggtitle("Barcode plot") +
    theme(
        legend.key = element_rect(fill = "grey"),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank()
    )
```

[image]

#### Input data

```r
input_string <- c(
    "bla bla bla bla",
    "<indig>fu fu</indig>",
    "<indig>fu fu</indig>",
    "bla bla bla bla bla bla.. bla bla bla bla bla",
    "<indig>fu</indig>?",
    "<indig>fu fu</indig>?",
    "bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla",
    "bla",
    "<indig>fu fu</indig>",
    "bla bla <indig>fu</indig>",
    "bla <indig>fu</indig>",
    "bla.. bla",
    "bla bla bla bla bla bla ??",
    "bla bla bla",
    "bla bla bla bla bla bla bla",
    "bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla",
    "bla bla <indig>fu</indig> bla<U+0001F923><U+0001F923><U+0001F923>"
)
```